# How to make a responsive navbar without bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How to make a responsive make the navbar collapse into a hamburger menu bar after a certain width **without bootstrap, but from scratch**?
[image]

**Here is the fiddle**https://jsfiddle.net/6951Lscu/

```css
    
    #myNavbar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}
    
.medium{
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.right-nav{
    padding: 8px 15px;
    float: right;
}


div.container{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 6px 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

div.container a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="myNavbar">
    <div class="container">
<ul>
  <li style="float:left"><a href="#home"><img class="navlogo" src="svg/navlogo.svg" alt=""></a></li>
   <li class="right-nav"><a href="#Kontakt"><span class="medium">KONTAKT</span></a></li> 
   <li class="right-nav"><a href="#Pris"><span class="medium">PRIS</span></a></li>
     <li class="right-nav"><a href="#Garantier"><span class="medium">GARANTIER</span></a></li>
  <li class="right-nav"><a href="#Ommeg"><span class="medium">OM MEG</span></a></li> 
</ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
    background: #181818;
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.inner {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 120px;
    color: #eee;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 40px;
}
nav > ul {
    float: right;
}
nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
nav > ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: #777;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: white;
}
nav > ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
}
nav > ul li ul li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
[type="checkbox"],
label {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        background: #222;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    label:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 5px;
        background: #777;
        margin: 7px 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px #777, 0px 20px 0px #777
    }
    [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
        display: block;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    nav a {
        color: #777;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        background: #222;
        text-indent: 20px;
    }
    nav > ul > li {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    nav > ul li ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav > ul li ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        float: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="inner">
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="nav" /><label for="nav"></label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Work</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: used Media Query .. Just Simple Html and Css Based if You dont want using bootstrap . see the snippet . for example ..

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to [Hanlin Chong's CodePen](https://codepen.io/hanlinC/pen/dJwil) which utilizes `@media` queries to handle responsive behavior based on `max-width` of the screen.

Or start with the basic W3Schools Responsive Navbar tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should read about @media rule in CSS3. Here is url [Click](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). There is no other way to do that without bootstrap. Good luck!